# "n" in genitive indefinite plural

Tags: grammatical-case

What would be the explanation for additional "n" in indefinite  genitive plural  of noun Bild and Kraft?

```
             Singular    Plural
Nominativ   eine Kraft   Kräfte
Genitiv     einer Kraft  Kräften <-- THIS
Dativ       einer Kraft  Kräften
Akkusativ   eine Kraft   Kräfte
```

https://dict.leo.org/german-english/bild

and

```
            Singular              Plural
Nominativ   ein Bild              Bilder
Genitiv     eines Bilds/​Bildes    Bildern <-- THIS
 Dativ      einem Bild            Bildern
Akkusativ   ein Bild              Bilder
```

https://dict.leo.org/chinesisch-deutsch/Kraft

Comment: Please click on left side book type icon beside the noun.

Answer (score 3):

LEO is simply wrong. Not only is there no 'n' in any of these genitive forms, the 'bestimmt'/'unbestimmt' feature doesn't affect *noun* inflection at all (it affects *adjective* inflection). I'm afraid their feature is broken both in particular and in general.

Answer (score 2):

The tables from the linked pages are wrong. Examples of genitive plural forms in connection with indefinite article words are:

> - Die Summe aller **Kräfte<s>n</s>** ist Null.
> - Er glaubte an die Wirkung irgendwelcher **Kräfte<s>n</s>**.
> - Er wurde wegen mancher **Bilder<s>n</s>** kritisiert.
> - Die Farben sämtlicher **Bilder<s>n</s>** waren ausgeblichen.

<sup>(Remark with respect to some comments: When a letter is striked through, such as <s>n</s> above, then this usually means: it's wrong with the letter, it's right without the letter.)</sup>

Notice that, for nouns, it would not make a difference, if a definite article would be used. The distinction becomes important only when we talk about adjectives, for which there is weak, strong, and mixed declension.

Comment: "Wegen Bildern" is acceptable because "wegen" can be construed either with genitive or dative. But all your other three examples are wrong.

Comment: *Sein Kunstgeschmack wurde manch Bilder röhrender Hirsche wegen in Zweifel gezogen.*

Comment: @fdb Could you asserts the mistakes in the sentence.

Comment: @ughitudhi. It should be Kräfte, Kräfte, Bilder, Bilder.

Comment: To clarify what I wrote before: "wegen mancher Bilder" (gen. pl.) is correct Standard German. "Wegen manchen Bildern" (dat. pl.) is now also considered acceptable. "Wegen mancher Bildern" is wrong.

Comment: Is the above explanation about your this sentence "But all your other three examples are wrong?

Comment: @ughitudhi. I should have written: "All four are wrong".

Comment: @fdb Thank you.

Comment: @fdb ??? The **n** is striked through in all four cases, right? Other readers usually understand that this means: the forms with **n** are wrong.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich. Ok, I can see it now (VERY faint on my screen).