# Genders in the "Babylon" dictionary

Tags: gender, dictionary, typo

I use this German-English dictionary from Babylon. It puts *die* in front of the German word *[Jahrtausend](http://107.6.141.14/definition/Jahrtausend/English)* from which I infer the word is feminine, but it is neuter in other dictionaries.

[image: screenshot_Jahrtausend]

**Is there any reason/explanation for that?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the German language.

Comment: From Babylon? Cuneiform I hope?

Comment: It may be because there is Tausend in neuter and there is Tausend in feminine, as in "the number 1000" https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tausend_Zahl. This is how they got it wrong.

Comment: I never heard of a dictionary called *Babylon*. I feel this is contraindicative to your idea that it was famous.

Comment: @Dan Thank you very much! You are the only one who actually answered the question. Others have all just questioned the question, as is usual here.

Comment: If you are interested in alternatives: reasonably good dictionaries are **Leo**  https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/  and **Dict-cc** https://www.dict.cc/

Comment: As for your question (which was *Why should a dictionary make such a mistake?*, the answer is: it shouldn't. - I also do not find Dan's explanation all too convincing. Still it is a regular thing: *das Jahrhundert*, *das Jahrzehnt*, *das Jahrfünft*...

Comment: The reason that questions are usually questioned here is, that a lot of them show no self-effort. For this question I can only say, that this site is about the German language and your question is about a mistake in a dictionary. While it may be an interesting question, it's unfortunately the wrong place to ask.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I guess I've seen people here who were let down by Leo. Oh, right, a Chinese guy was puzzled by wrong info there.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann please don't recommend it... https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54746/n-in-genitive-indefinite-plural/54747#54747

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann My question is not that.

Comment: @Sasan  Well, yes, now that you edited the question, it is indeed different. Now it is "Is there a reason for that?" - Answer: No, there is no reasonable reason for claiming that *Jahrtausend* was femininum. It simply isn't. It is a mistake in the online dictionary. (But I think the question is a viable question now.)

Comment: @Sasan: Please add a screenshot from your source. It seems to have a paywall (for me), so I cannot take a look at it.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Screenshot added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

German compound words take the gender of the rightmost word in the meaning in which is was used to create the compound, e.g. *der Elternteil* vs. *das Fertigteil*.

German has two genders for the word "*Tausend*", depending on the meaning. If an entity consisting of thousand smaller entities is meant, it's *neuter*.

If we, however, relate to the "number 2000", *Tausend* [becomes feminine](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tausend_Zahl).
Usage examples:

> Trotz heißer Temperaturen kamen am Wochenende **an die 1000** Besucher zum Klimaschutz-Aktionstag des Kreises in Bistensee. (note the article doesn't belong to Besucher but to the "1000")
>
> Insgesamt sollen **an die 1000** Gefangene freigelassen werden

Compare:

> "Ich habe **eine 1** in Mathe bekommen!"

Low budget free online dictionaries seem to employ scripts for gender tagging, in this case based on the "basis" word. As the basis word has two genders, the script appears to have taken on the feminine version of the word with the meaning "number 2000" and applied it to the compound.

---

On a side note, as for the usage of the said dictionary, I would recommend using the most authoritative sources such as Duden, DWDS or Collins Cobuild/Oxford, who have both the resources to avoid such mistakes and the renowned reputation to care about. Also refer to the list https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9535/9739 (apart from Leo, which sometimes would have weird mistakes confusing people and forcing them to ask on stack exchange, and is in general not quite informative, as it does not cite *any* usage cases for your [enter link description here](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/Jahrtausend) in question).

Comment: This is a hypothesis on the genesis of this mistake in the "Babylon" dictionary. It sounds plausible at first. However, if the mistake was produced by a sloppy algorithm, it should repeat. The entry for Jahrhundert though states correctly *das Jahrhundert*, see: 107.6.141.14/definition/Jahrhundert/English. Same for *das Jahrzehnt*. And even the much rarer *Jahrfünft* is correctly reported as *das*, see 107.6.141.14/definition/Jahrf%C3%BCnft/English. So, how does this fit into the hypothesis of *die Jahrtausend* being algorithm-generated?

Comment: This answer is not correct. We say “an die 1000 Besucher” not because “1000” is (supposedly) feminine, but because “Besucher” is plural. It is like “Wo sind die fünf Kinder?”.

Comment: @fdb   I think it is hard to decide where the *die* in *an die tausend Besucher* comes from. Why are you so convinced that Dan's idea is wrong? Do you have arguments for it? (I mean, not only that your idea is *also* possible; rather, why your idea is more plauble than Dan's?)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann. To begin with: you yourself write "tausend" (numeral) not "Tausend" (noun)..

Comment: @fdb  Spelling conventions are not necessarily proof of underlying semantic or syntactic structure.

Comment: @fdb please explain. Do you challenge Dudens statement that Tausend as a numeral is feminine?